# how to restrict placement of client data to specific nodes in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am working on hadoop and I am currently trying to find out how to make the file given by the client to be stored in specific nodes in the cluster.
The client wants the files or chunks to be stored in particular nodes or particular files but not in all.

**I am searching for a way to specify which nodes will be used to store the file we put in HDFS.**

Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **[HDFS-385](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385)** you can do that. This feature provides a way  to write code that specifies how HDFS should allocate replicas of blocks of a file. You can visit **[this](https://github.com/facebook/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/BlockPlacementPolicyConfigurable.java)** if you need some help on how to write your own block placement policy.

HTH